# "Гривна" или "гривня"?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно: "гривна" или "гривня" (речь об украинской валюте)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Гри́вна (укр. гривня, IPA: /ˈɦrɪu̯ɲɑ/) — национальная валюта Украины (с 1996 года), названная в честь древнерусской гривны. Гривна делится на 100 копеек (укр. копійка).

В общероссийском классификаторе валют для украинской валюты установлено название «гривна».

Украинские официальные источники... указывают наименование денежной единицы по-русски «гривня», а не «гривна». В обиходе на Украине можно встретить оба варианта названия.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0

Comment: Вопрос задан 25 янв '12 в 11:04, — ответ 25 янв '12 в 11:05 ========= Автор мероприятия уложился в минуту и наградил себя птицей? Куда смотрит налоговая!

Comment: @shampar Подробнее о вопросах-ответах данного пользователя можно почитать в моём ответе на Мете. https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213/Всё-сам-вопрос-ответ-оценка-приём-правильно-приемлемо/214#214

Answer (score 1):

Древнерусская денежная единица называлась ГРИВНА (отсюда ГРИВЕННИК — название монеты в 10 копеек). Поэтому и денежную единицу современной Украины по-русски тоже стали называть гривной, просто по привычке и по традиции. ЭТО НЕПРАВИЛЬНО, потому что сами украинцы на своих деньгах пишут ГРИВНЯ и произносят, конечно, так же. Традиция — штука упрямая, но ее все же можно переломить.

Comment: А почему неправильно? Британский pound (*паунд*)  вообще фунтом называем.  Я тоже за гривню, но тут требуется мотивация более агрументированная, чем простая отсылка к языку оригинала.

Comment: "...украинцы на своих деньгах пишут ГРИВНЯ..." — на заборах тоже много чего пишут. Вы бы транскрипцией поинтересовались или услышали, как читается. Дословно — [ГРЫВНЯ]. Впрочем, у русских свои правила - Белоруссия — Беларусь, Молдавия — Молдова, на Украину — в Украину. Ведь всегда можно придумать исключение или сказать, что: "я так привык" или "так исторически сложилось, что мы называем...".